# Whats the correct way to use and refer to a slugfield in a django 1.3

Tags: django, django-templates, slug

Whats the correct way to use and refer to a slugfield in a django 1.3

for example the following code should link via slug to a generic view however the NoReverseMatch error is received.

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'single_post' with arguments '('', u'post-2')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

From my understanding this saying that the error lies in the template however being a newbie and having tried many different variations on {% url single_post slug=post.slug %} this may not be the case.

Could someone please explain why this is happening so that I can understand where the problem lies andhow to fix.

Ive tried {% url single_post slug=post.slug %},{% url single_post slug %}{% url single_post slug=post.slug %} and many other variations

All help is greatly appreciated

model

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=True)
```

url

```
   url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[a-z-]+)/$', list_detail.object_detail,
         {'queryset': Post.objects.all(), 'template_object_name': 'post', 'slug_field': 'slug'}, name="single_post"),
```

template

```
{% url single_post slug post.slug %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regex doesn't allow for numeric values. Try:

```
(?P<slug>[\w-]+)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however no luck. Is the regex definitely the issue, or could it be coming form another area. In your opinion? Thanks

Comment: Hmm. The regex seems like the culprit here. [a-z-]+ will not match: post-2. [-\w]+ does in my Django applications. \w will match [a-zA-Z0-9_] according to the Python regular Expression Syntax reference: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re-syntax

Answer (score 2):

In your template, assuming `post` is an instance of your model:

```
{% url single_post post.slug %}
```

Your url regex should look like the following:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ...
```

To test the above regex, try to access a few posts directly in your browser with a variety of valid slugs and see if they works.  Once this is done, start testing the url names.

Answer (score 2):

A slug value can contain any `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` and `-`. The first 3 are represented by the special character `w` and since `-` itself is a special character, we need to use represent them both using a backslash `\`. So the correct expression becomes

```
url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', ...
```

At least this is what is working in my case.

Answer (score 2):

In Django 1.5 the slug validator uses this regex:

```
slug_re = re.compile(r'^[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+$')
```

See https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/core/validators.py#L106

You can use this regex in urls.py:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$', ...
```

In earlier versions it was `[-\w]+` but I guess in Python3 \w matches non ascii characters like umlauts.