# Having trouble with slug

Tags: django, django-templates, slug

I was writing a model online shop django app, wanted to incorporate slug in it. Having trouble in opening a page.
This is my model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils .text import slugify

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("OnlineShop:order", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

def pre_save_customer_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    slug = slugify(instance.customer_name)
    exists = Customer.objects.filter(slug = slug).exists()
    if exists:
        slug = "%s-%s" % (slug,instance.id)
    instance.slug=slug

pre_save.connect(pre_save_customer_receiver, sender = Customer)
```

This is my view:

```
def customer(request):
    customer_list = Customer.objects.all()
    template_path = 'OnlineShop/customer.html'
    context={
        'customer_list':customer_list,
    }
    return render(request,template_path,context)

def order(request,slug):
    Customer = Customer.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    ''' some code from here '''
```

And my template customer.html:

```
<h1>List of Customers:</h1>
<ul>
    {% for customer in customer_list %}
        <li><a href='{% url 'order' customer.slug %}'>{{ customer.customer_name }}<br></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[image: NoReverseMatch at /OnlineShop/]

This is my urls.py

```
       from django.conf.urls import url
       from . import views

       urlpatterns=[
       url(r'^$',views.customer, name='customer'),
       url(r'^customer/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$',views.order, name='order'),
       ]
```

Is the problem in the template? What is wrong?

Comment: Can you edit your question with `urls.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you've defined your `urls.py` like below,

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from . import views

onlineshop_patterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.customer, name='customer'),
    url(r'^customer/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', views.order, name='order'),
]

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^OnlineShop/', include(onlineshop_patterns)),
    # ...
]
```

Read [Reverse resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) and [Regex for SlugField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717838/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-and-refer-to-a-slugfield-in-a-django-1-3).

Comment: The reason why I am asking about the problem in template is that in the template when I replace customer.slug with customer.id in that case at least views.customer is successfully called. There I don't face any trouble. The moment I have customer.slug in the template the problem arises.

Comment: Can you post a sample slug ?

Comment: Okay figured out the problem, TY. I had to modify the regex for slug in the url from (?P<slug>[\w-]+) to (?P<slug>[\w-]*) and a slight modification in the order view the code of which I haven't posted.  :)